# Can not connect to SQL Server via Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

Here is my code below that I'm just trying to send df to the server, the same code was working when I use the local server without user and pass, I've tried all the combination. Is there any other way around or I'm missing something?

Additional Note: SQL server is connected through company VPN is it affected?

```
import pandas as pd
from fast_to_sql import fast_to_sql as fts
df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\han.37\Desktop\test\Copy of 01012020.xlsx')
#send to SQL server
sql_conn = (
r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
r'SERVER=GRATHDB03\REPLICA;'
r'DATABASE=DATAWRHS-PM;'
r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
r'UID=EMEA\han.37;'
r'PWD=****;'
)
conn_db = pyodbc.connect(sql_conn)

create_statement = fts.fast_to_sql(df, "Contact Patterntest2", conn_db, if_exists="append", temp=False)

conn_db.commit()
conn_db.close()
```

And the error is;

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')

Comment: does this work when you use SSMS or Azure Datastudio? also where is the port specific?

Comment: SSMS definitely not working but don't know azure data studio?

Comment: Try to connect by using IP address. By the way, if your connection is trusted, you don't need to indicate uid/pwd

Comment: Yeah, I just tried all the combinations :)

Comment: Please show that your "combination" with IP address. You have tne NAMED instance so you should indicate the correct port with the IP address

Comment: While this may not resolve your immediate issue, consider changing your ODBC Driver since the [SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI) remains deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15). Check your list of installed drivers by running command in PowerShell: `Get-OdbcDriver`. Look for `ODBC Driver ## for SQL Server` or install free from MS.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this.

```
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=server_name\\SQLEXPRESS;"
                        "Database=TestDB;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

#cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#cursor.execute("select * from Actions")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Actions')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))


# with login creds


pyodbc.connect("Driver = {SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"               
               "Server = Server_Name;"
               "Database = Database_Name;"
               "username = User_Name;"
               "password = User_Password;"
               "Trusted_Connection = yes;")
```